# Tkinter error, binding an entry object with a function, 2 arguments given, 1 needed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter. In order to learn Tkinter, i have followed [this tutorial](http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/), and i tried to use it for my new little project. However, i have an error when pressing enter on my entry box that i have created. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter

class PocketDEX(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.labelVariable.set("Cuvântul căutat este:")
        label = Tkinter.Label(self, textvariable = self.labelVariable, anchor="w")
        label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.EnterPressed)

    def EnterPressed(self):
        print "It worked!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PocketDEX(None)
    app.title('★ PocketDEX ★')
    app.mainloop()
```

The error i got is the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: EnterPressed() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I don't understand exaclty why there is 2 arguments given, i am using Python 2.7.6 on Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other argument is the `event`. This is normal. The event has attributes associated with it that you can access. For example:

```
event.keysym
>>> 'Return'
```

The easiest way to handle this is to just modify the callback method to accept the event argument:

```
def EnterPressed(self, event):
    print "It worked!"
```

More info: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm